# Additional automatic Text appearing in Overleaf

Tags: errors, overleaf

In overleaf, I am getting text below automatically when I compile .tex file. I don't know where this is coming from. Any idea why this is appearing and how to solve this problem? I would highly appreciate your suggestion.

```
[iFrameSizer]iFrameResizer0:0:1:size[iFrameSizer]iFrameResizer0:0:0:autoResize:false[iFrameSizer]iFrameResizer0:0:300:initdealfinder-io:syn[iFrameResizerChild]Ready
```

Comment: do you get that just in the editor or actually in your pdf, they look more like javascript messages than tex, so it would be hard to see how they could get in the pdf. Either way, you should probably ask overleaf support rather than here

Comment: Both in the code and pdf. My code does not work when I get that code in pdf.

Comment: is it really in the pdf (if you download it and look at it in a pdf reader) or just the built in pdf view in overleaf. It looks like your browser crashed, I would start by connecting from a different browser, or as I say report the issue to overleaf, there does not appear to be any tex question here as that isn't a tex error message